# mod_csrf breaking php returned json

Tags: php, jquery, json, csrf

I'm using the Apache module called mod_csrf for preventing cross site request forgery.

When I enable the module, it seems to work at first glance.
My pages are being injected with the data:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<!--
csrfInsert("csrfpId", "asdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf_BCak3DuxfDzNMFAw2UTDeycZZzU14ooFOyYG4Cb_N8=");
//-->
</script>
```

The csrfpId above is faked, but this is the javascript that is injected into my pages when the module is enabled.
From my understanding of what the module is supposed to do, I believe that this is the expected behavior.

The problem is that my page uses Jquery to make a post request to a php script in order to retrieve JSON.
When the module is disabled, the JSON is returned from the php script as expected. An example looks like this:

```
[{"name":"itema","count":6},{"name":"itemb","count":11},{"name":"itemc","count":4}]
```

However, when I enable the csrf module, the JSON returned is broken. An example of the broken JSON looks like this:

```
[{"name":"imtea","count":6},{"name":"itemb","count":11},{"name":"itemc","count
```

Above is just one example, but this seem to be happening on all Jquery Post requests to a PHP script that returns JSON.

Initially when I enabled the module ,I received errors because I did not set and options for the module. I later added the following module options:

```
CSRF_Enable on
CSRF_ScriptPath /csrf.js
```

When I first set these options, it failed becasue I didn't have the csrf.js file in the correct location. This could be see because of a 404 error. 
I corrected this and the 404 went away. However, regardless of the options being set or not, the JSON problem still exists.

Any ideas?